# Batch Script to execute command only for files above a certain size,

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick, image-resizing

I am trying to run the Imagemagick mogrify only on files that are above a 1,500kb.
The Imagemagick command would be `magick mogrify *.jpg -resize 50%% *.jpg`

So after researching on my own I have ended up with this

```
@echo off
setlocal
set maxbytesize=1500000

FOR /F %%A IN (*.jpg) DO set size=%%~zA

if %size% GTR %maxbytesize% (
    magick mogrify *.jpg -resize 50%% *.jpg
)
```

This doesn't work and I have no idea where to go from here.
I have read on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38943/use-mogrify-to-resize-large-files-while-ignoring-small-ones that I may have to filter through the list first though I don't know how to implement it.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks for reading this post.

Comment: There is in real only one command line needed as replacement for everything you posted: `@for %%I in (*.jpg) do if %%~zI GTR 1500000 magick.exe mogrify "%%I" -resize 50%% "%%I"` whereby better would be `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.jpg /A-D /B 2^>nul') do if %%~zI GTR 1500000 magick.exe mogrify "%%I" -resize 50%% "%%I"`. Open a command prompt window, run `for /?`, read the output help carefully and completely, run `if /?` and read again the entire output help and run `dir /?` and read once again the this time shorter output help.

Answer (score 2):

Your value will be replaced through each iteration of the files (besides the fact that `/F` causing another issue here as well, see `for /?` for more detail)

So only the value of the last file is set as the value. Additionally, even if they were not, you are doing `magick` on `*.jpg`, which is all `jpg` files in the directory. So if the last file seems to match the size, all files will be resized, which will kind of defeating the purpose, right?

All you really need is to iterate through files, match the size each time, then perform the action:

```
@echo off
for %%A IN (*.jpg) DO if %%~zA gtr 1500000 magick mogrify "%%~A" -resize 50%% "%%~A"
```

Comment: `for %%A IN (*.jpg) DO` accesses the file system to get the matching file names one after the other and assigns each file name to the loop variable `A` __always__ without `"` even on containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~``. For that reason the modifier `~` is in this case unnecessary and just makes the processing of the file names a very little bit slower for removing never existing `"` which of course no user would ever notice as computers are nowadays very fast. The double quotes around `%%A` are of course necessary, but not the modifier `~`.

Comment: Yes, 100% @Mofi, it is a matter of preference. I just want to have control of the quotations.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of being different, here's an example which pre-filters the target files prior to the `do` portion of the `for` loop, instead of passing it everything, and then filtering their sizes.

Additionally, I have modified the `mogrify` parameters, because if I remember correctly, the resizing automatically overwrites the source file.

Please remember to input your actual Source and Magick Paths on lines `4` and `5`, before you run the script.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensons

Set "SourcePath=S:\ource\Directory"
Set "MagickPath=%ProgramFiles%\ImageMagick-7.1.0-Q16-HDRI"

If Not Exist "%MagickPath%\magick.exe" GoTo :EOF
CD /D "%SourcePath%" 2>NUL || GoTo :EOF

Set "}=%CD:\=\\%\\"
For /F Tokens^=6^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe DataFile Where
 "Drive='%}:~,2%' And Path='%}:~2%' And Extension='jpg' And FileSize>'1500000'"
 Get Name /Format:MOF 2^>NUL'
) Do "%MagickPath%\magick.exe" mogrify -resize 50%% "%%~nxG"
```

*As a side note, just be aware that if you have a `.jpg` file with a very large sizes, even after resizing to `50%`, there may still be files in excess of `1500000` bytes. In those cases, it may be prudent to run the script more than once.*